# Deleting files from an App being developed using Android Studio

Tags: android

Is there a way to delete files from an app I am developing using Android Studio?  I delete files that I do not need and Android Studio retrieve them automatically when I open the app that I work on.

Comment: Can you post some code? Which files you want to delete?

Comment: I have xml drawable files for icons that I do not need.  I delete them through Android Studio but they come back.  Even I go outside through Explorer to the drawable directory and delete them but they come back when I start Android Studio.  I am not using the files in any code anymore.